# Getting an error on inserting a row in view in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to insert a row in the view. on doing so I am getting an error. how can I resolve this error?
here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW DETAILS
AS 
SELECT null as pSerial_number, null as pname,NULL AS additional_field1 
from student;
insert into details (pSerial_number,pname,additional_field1) values (priya,41);
```

> error:Error Code: 1348. Column 'pSerial_number' is not updatable

***note: all columns that I am adding in view are not present in table.***

Comment: You cannot add columns into the view output. Use `SELECT * FROM details CROSS JOIN (SELECT {values and column names list});`. And values amount in your `VALUES` clause (2) does not match the columns amount in columns list (3).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you can't add a column into a view using an `insert` command. An `insert` command inserts data into a table. A view is a projection of a select command, therefore to insert a column into a view you need to change your view. So it should be:

```
create or replace view details
 as
SELECT null as pSerial_number, 
       null as pname,
       NULL AS additional_field1 
from student;
```

This is enough to add the `additional_field1` to that view.

The problem here is that your view makes no sense at all because it is listing all rows from `student` table as `nulls` for those three manual fields.

For instance say that the structure of `student` table is

```
serial_number varchar,
name varchar,
additional_field1 int
```

And the values in it are:

```
serial_number   name    additional_field1
   AD5424       Test1      1
   AD5421       Test2      2
   AD5422       Test3      3
```

If you run above code (to create the view) and then you run a `select` statement on it like `select * from details` the response you will receive will be:

```
serial_number   name    additional_field1
   null         null      null
   null         null      null
   null         null      null
```

So instead you map your view accordingly your table columns like this:

```
create or replace view details
 as
SELECT serial_number as pSerial_number, 
       name as pname,
       additional_field1 AS additional_field1 
from student;
```

And now if you run the `select` statement on it `select * from details` you will get:

```
pSerial_number   pname    additional_field1
   AD5424       Test1      1
   AD5421       Test2      2
   AD5422       Test3      3
```

Note the name of the columns and the values of the student table.

I hope this helps to clarify what a view is and how you can change it.